# Detect When Flash Loads Remote Item

Tags: flash, external-dependencies

I have a flash player that loads in some additional features from flash files on other sites... for example, the main flash player on on site1, but it displays an animation that is actually housed on site2.

How can I detect when (and where) the main flash player is going to for information?

Can I trace the network traffic somehow to see this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to use a product called "Wireshark" to run a network capture and I found the HTTP GET requests in the resulting trace. If you know what you're doing you can probably filter the results a lot better - but luckily for me the colour coding highlighted exactly what I needed in bright green, which saved me having to search through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wireshark filter. Simply filter for http traffic. You can also use it to follow a tcp conversation and see the ascii version of the actual request.

Comment: Yep - that's what I discovered last May, which is why I posted the answer - in case other people had the some problem. Cheers.